# Misunderstand things

Tags: grammar

I heard a person saying :

> We can misunderstand things wrong.

These are two negations. How can he misunderstand something that is already wrong?

I can't really understand the grammar of this sentence. Why can't we say :

> misunderstand things right.

Even the grammar of this sentence is confusing.
Shouldn't the sentence be: **we can understand things wrong** Is it the same as  **We can misunderstand things wrong** ?

.

Comment: If I heard "We can misunderstand things wrong" from a reasonably literate person I'd assume it was said with a bit of humor.  "Correct" would either "We can misunderstand things" or "We can understand things incorrectly".  ("Wrong" is generally considered to be an adjective, whereas an adverb is called for in the context, and the adverb "wrongly" is rarely used.)  "We can misunderstand things correctly" is somewhat nonsensical (when not used in an ironic sense).

Comment: ("We can misunderstand things incorrectly" implies that there is a "correct" way to misunderstand something, and an incorrect way, and the incorrect form of misunderstanding occurred.  Again, this might be said in a sort of ironic sense to indicate that the misunderstanding being discussed is not the "usual" misunderstanding of this subject, but something different.)

Comment: This sentence is fine the way it is. It is grammatically correct. We | can misunderstand | things | wrong = Subject | verb phrase | direct object | **objective complement** || The **objective complement** is a noun or adjective that completes the direct object "things." The adjective "wrong" modifies the direct "things" and helps to complete the meaning of the verb "can misunderstand." **Objective Complement**—John E. Warriner. Warriner’s English Grammar and Composition. Fifth Course. Liberty Edition. Orlando, Florida: Harcourt, Brace, and Jovanovich. 1986. 37.

Comment: Thank you @ArchDenton. It was really confusing at first. Sorry To complete the question is it the same as ***we can understand things wrong**.

Comment: That sounds about right. We can misunderstand things wrong. = We can understand things wrong.

Comment: The sentence is *not* "fine the way it is". It sounds like nonsense to native speakers. @ArchDenton, if you want to make statements like this, complete with references, you should make them answers and let people vote on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would have to work very hard to imagine a context in which

> We can misunderstand things wrong

would work.

I don't know where you saw or heard this, but you should plan on saying

> We can misunderstand things when we don't listen carefully.